# Calling Parent Function with the Same Signature/Name

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, extends

A and B have function with the same signature -- let's assume : `foo($arg)` -- and that `class A extends B`.

Now I have an instance:

```
$a = new A();

$a.foo($data);
```

Can I also run the parent's (B's) `foo()` function through `$a` or was it overridden?

Thanks!
Nimi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is overridden but if you want to use both you can do this:

```
function parentFoo($arg)
{
    return parent::foo($arg);
}
```

If you want that the child function calls the parent function do this:

```
function foo($arg)
{
    $result = parent::foo($arg);
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

See this URL for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This approach is clear but is there any way to access the foo() from external class without generating B object?

Answer (score 7):

`.` is the string concatenation operator in PHP. To call methods, use `->`.

To call an overridden method, use `parent::method()`

```
class B {
  public function foo($data) {
    echo 'B';
  }
}

class A extends B{
  public function foo($data) {
    parent::foo($data);
    echo 'A';
  }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo($data); // BA
$b = new B();
$b->foo($data); // B
```

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, no, you can't call the parent's foo() method through an object of class A as the only foo() method the object A understands in its public API is its own foo() method. You probably need to think about your design. If B's foo() is providing different functionality to A's foo() then should one override the other? Or you need to think about A's foo() calling B's foo() via parent::foo() - assuming you want B's foo() called every time A's foo() is called. Or use another pattern. If A's foo() isn't always appropriate for an object of A then you might want to look at the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) patttern's.

If you're starting out with OO programming I can't recommend the [Gang of Four book](http://www.pearsoned.co.uk/bookshop/detail.asp?item=171742) highly enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the parents methods with `parent::foo()`

Answer (score 0):

In class A you can write

```
parent::foo($param);
```

to call the base classes foo(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I also run the parent's foo() function through $a or it was override ?

Not from the "outside". Say:

```
<?php
class A {
    function talk( ) {
        return 'Hello world';
    }
}
class B extends A {
    function talk( ) {
        return 'Goodbye world';
    }
}

$b = new B;
$b->talk( ); // Goodbye world.
```

In this example, it's not possible to have $b->talk output A::talk( ), other than proxying that through B. If you need to have the result from A instead of B, you might want to explain your dilemma; that's a problem you shouldn't run into, and if you do, the chances are the design isn't optimal.

Comment: Where does `$b` come from in your example?

Comment: Ehr, well, typo's happen :)  Edited the example accordingly.